# Python tkinter canvas postscript: how to force form-feed

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating a double-sided form using

```
    canvas.create_text(x, y, anchor='sw', text='some text')
```

The canvas' size is given by width=788, height=1120 which conforms to A4.

When having created the front side of the form, I want to do the form feed but don't know how to make canvas recognize the desired page break.

I tried providing **'\u000c'** (unicode form feed) or **'\f'** (ASCII form feed) to the 'text' argument of create_text, but it didn't work: when printing the postscript file generated by

```
    canvas.postscript(file='temp.ps')
```

only one page will be printed. The control char is ignored.

Can someone help?

(Ubuntu 18.0, Python 3.6)

Comment: Far as i know, `postscript` does not support `form-feed`.

Comment: PostScript doesn't work like a teletype, and even if it did it doesn't use Unicode. Text to a PostScript interpreter is just text, the content of text strings has no effect on the graphics state. So no, form-feed will do nothing when its in a text string in PostScript program. No idea what tkinter will do with it.. If you want to send a completed page to the device you use the showpage operator. At a guess, you need to create a new canvas, I sort of suspect you can't have multiple pages on a single canvas but I know nothing about tkinter. In any event; not a PostScript question.